# How to stop Apple Watch from unlocking a Mac with lid closed

Tags: sleep-wake, apple-watch, unlock

I am using the Apple Watch to unlock my Macbook Pro Retina (Late 2013) and it works reasonably well, almost too well:  When I stop working with the Macbook and close the lid, but stay in proximity, I will very soon get a notification that the Mac was unlocked using the Apple Watch. Then a minute later I will get another one, and another one.  I have gotten up to 7, but most of the time it stops after two or three.  Opening the lid right after one of these notifications confirms that the computer is unlocked.  I suspect that this has something to do with Powernap.

I do not want to disable either Powernap or Unlock with Apple Watch.  Is this a bug I just have to live with?

How could I debug the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the current versions of MacOS and WatchOS.

Comment: Oh man, it looks like Mojave is affected again. I'm not sure about Catalina. My MacBook with Mojave is constantly unlocked and, on top of that, somehow some keystrokes are sent, so I may end up with some document completely destroyed, full of `nnnnn` characters and spaces.